# Cannot reinstantiate jQuery plugin after destroy

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making my own jquery plugin and can't reinit the plugin after destroying it. I've reduced the code to its basics for clarity. I've tried to research this a lot but it seems everyone creates these plugins in vastly different ways. The boilerplate that i've used as reference is here https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js

When I click on the init button, the text goes red. Then pressing the destroy button makes the text black. But then pressing init again doesn't make the text red.

```
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="init">init</button>
  <button class="destroy">destroy</button>
</div>
```

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

  "use strict";

  let pluginName = "myPlugin",
      defaults = {
        color: 'red',
      };

  function Plugin(element, options) {

    this.element = element;

    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.wrapper = '';
    this.text = '';

    this.init();
  }


  $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {

    init: function () {
      let o = this.settings;

      this.wrapper = $(this.element);
      this.text = this.wrapper.find('p');

      this.text.css('color', o.color)
    },

  });

  $.fn.destroy = function() {
    return this.each(function () {

      let plugin = $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName);
      plugin.text.css('color', 'black')

    })

  };

  $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" +
               pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);




$(document).ready(function () {

  let x = '';

  $(document).on("click", ".init", function () {
    x = $('#banner-message').myPlugin();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".destroy", function () {
    x.destroy()
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add this inside of the destroy method

```
   $(this).removeData('plugin_' + pluginName);
```